# How to get hold of intermediate results?

Tags: apache-spark

I'm using [Apache Spark](http://spark.apache.org/) as MapReduce implementation and was wondering whether there is a way to get hold of intermediate results. The simple API allows to `collect` the results from the triggering application once all the map steps have completed, in its simplest form e.g.

```
val results = mapResult.collect()
```

I'm interested in collecting intermediate map results as they complete. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: When you talk about intermediate results, what are you referring to exactly? Are you trying to use the data result from a map operation before starting a reduce action?

Comment: exactly, suppose I am getting a bunch of MSE and I need the minimum but it takes several days. If I have intermediate results I can find out the minimum MSE **up to now** as opposed to waiting for several days to get an idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use dataframe's `cache()` method to cache the computation result and so when you call the `action` later then it'll use the cached result instead of re-computing the DAG. Something like:

```
# caches the result so the action called after this will use this cached
# result instead of re-computing the DAG
results.cache() 

results.show(1)
```

Later, you may want to free up the memory used for caching the result with:

```
results.unpersist()
```